# How to test email from ubuntu localhost

Tags: php, smtp, localhost, ubuntu-14.04

I am developing the email queuing App in **PHP** and I want to test if the mail is sent or not properly. As per my knowledge, I know the following methods

1. Sendmail.
2. Postfix.

But these methods require **SMTP**. Is there any other method to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use phpmailer class. PHPMailer is a good choice

```
<?php

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

//Send mail using gmail
if($send_using_gmail){
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"; // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Port = 465; // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username = "your-gmail-account@gmail.com"; // GMAIL username
    $mail->Password = "your-gmail-password"; // GMAIL password
}

//Typical mail data
$mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
$mail->SetFrom($email_from, $name_from);
$mail->Subject = "My Subject";
$mail->Body = "Mail contents";

try{
    $mail->Send();
    echo "Success!";
} catch(Exception $e){
    //Something went bad
    echo "Fail - " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

[phpmailer class](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php)

Comment: Thank you manish for the answer but this have the dependency of PHP Mailer and moreover it is sending the actual mail. I will prefer a method that only shows how the mail look like when sent.